# How to read an untrusted certificate in Python

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to read a certificate from a local connection using Python. When I access it via a browser, an SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN appears, and I just need to accept it to continue.

Using code:

I added this context:

```
context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.check_hostname = False
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

with socket.create_connection((hostname, port)) as sock:
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname) as ssock:
        cert = ssock.getpeercert()
        print(cert)
```

As result the cert cames empty
I noticed that it does a handshake with SSL, but when reading it, I can't issue information like the "commonName".